# parse a string in javascript

Tags: regex, parsing

I want to get file name from the below string in javascript. I am trying an regex to get file name (test_filename).

**/1/3/2/test1/test2/test_filename.html**

I wish to parse from the back rather than front because in above url /test2 may or may not come.

Any idea on this.

Comment: did you want to get the filename only on the path which has the strings `test1` or `test1/test2` ?

Answer (score 0):

Better to find the last `/` in the String and cut the name part:

```
var str = "/1/3/2/test1/test2/test_filename.html";
var fileName = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user lastIndexOf to get the position of the last / in the string...

```
var s = '/1/3/2/test1/test2/test_filename.html';
alert(s.substr(s.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
```

if you need to remove the .html too....

```
var s = '/1/3/2/test1/test2/test_filename.html';
s = s.substr(s.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
alert(s.substr(0, s.lastIndexOf('.')));
```